# Fullcalendar: Dont make weeks/rows with events higher

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I have a calendar with `dayGridMonth` view.

When I create 1 event, the row with the week increases in height a tiny bit. That's not that bad, but when I create another event, the row increases very much and makes the calendar look ugly.

You can see the exact problem in a [Codepen from their offical website](https://fullcalendar.io/demos).

As you can see, the row height has increased: [Screenshot from codepen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17ScD.png)

**BUT:**
In the [Demo on their Website](https://fullcalendar.io/demos), this does not happen. This is the behaviour I want. How do I achieve this? I was unable to find a tutorial for anything like this.

Answer (score 1):

I actually found it.

This behaviour is caused by [dayMaxEvents](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/dayMaxEvents)

I found it in the Demo [DragAndDropDemo.js](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-site-static/blob/main/src/demos/DragAndDropDemo.js)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).